# After installing LLVM, how do I compile and run a small project?

Tags: c++, windows, llvm

After having installed LLVM, I try following the Kaleidoscope tutorial on how to build a small language.

However, trying to compile with clang++, I get several errors.

First, the IDE cannot find the include files. However, I fixed this by pointing the IDE to the include directory inside the LLVM build directory.

Next, the linker says it cannot find object files.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and running Windows 10.

Can someone write a foolproof step-by-step guide on how to build a small app with some of the include files? This includes making clang++ aware on how to find the necessary files.

Thanks.

Comment: You have to pass an argument to the linker that specifies the path of the required files. This should all be in the Clang project documentation.

Comment: I cant find it anywhere.

Comment: Use [`llvm-config`](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-config.html) tool to output the arguments, see http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl08.html#putting-it-all-together